# How does website identity different user by cities automatically?

Tags: django, web, identity

I'm using Django to build a website,I need a function,that website can automatically identify the cities of the users ,and then I will supply different content for users from different cities.

But I have no clue what kind of technology  I need to use.

I heard something about google map api,but not sure.Anybody has such experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using django you can use [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/docs/geoip.html#example)

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
g = GeoIP()
ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', None)
if ip:
    city = g.city(ip)['city']
else:
    city = 'Unknow city'
```